# How to generate a stand-alone React app project in Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I am building a ASP.NET Core 2 API with a administration UI in React.

I don't want to mix the API and the UI in the same project (1) but I do want to include the React app as a standalone project within the solution so it gets built by Visual Studio.

Doing a "mixed" ASP.NET Core 2 + React project is straightforward in Visual Studio but I could not find a project template for just a React application.

How can I create the React UI project in my solution?

(1) Because the API is much more important than the UI, and I don't want to delay a push to the API because of a problem with the UI.

Comment: You'll want a task runner, like Grunt Gulp or Webpack